# Non greedy mode of parsing multiline string with grep

Tags: regex, grep, regex-greedy

I have a file:

```
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
a rs1
a rs2
a rs3
b rs4
b rs5
b rs6
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
```

where *rsN* is random stuff.

I'm trying to get last line with *a* and first line with *b*:

```
a rs3
b rs4
```

with:

```
> grep -Po "(?s)^a.*?$.*?^b.*?$" test.regexp
a rs1
a rs2
a rs3
b rs4
```

but apparently I'm missing something.

thanks.

Comment: If I were in your shoes, I'd use `awk` for this.

Comment: don't have a lot of awk knowledge, but will try to use it, thanks.

Comment: ignorance of the tool aside, `awk` is the tool for you to use.

Comment: For the record, grep only handles a single line at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you can try with `awk`.

```
awk '$1=="a"{a=$0;next}$1=="b"{print a; print $0;exit}' file
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
a rs1
a rs2
a rs3
b rs4
b rs5
b rs6
bla bla bla
bla bla bla
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '$1=="a"{a=$0;next}$1=="b"{print a; print $0;exit}' file
a rs3
b rs4
```